Ho to set up virtual interface with netplan to communicate with IP-device?
I have an IP-device that connects via ethernet and then communicates over UDP. The IP-device has hardcoded IP address (169.254.241.10). This is my draft netplan configuration:
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager


  ethernets:
    eth0:
      link-local: []
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      optional: true
      addresses:
      - 169.254.241.1/24
      routes:
      - to: 169.254.241.10/32
        via: 169.254.241.1
        metric: 0
        
  vlans:
    veth10:
      id: 10
      link: eth0
      link-local: []
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      addresses:
      - 169.254.241.100/24  

in my understanding then if i send something to 169.254.241.100 netplan-link has to reroute it to 169.254.241.10, but when I try to sniff through wireshark device veth10 I don't catch any packets coming/going. On eth0 I am able to catch broadcasted UDP packets from IP-device but not sent from myself
Edit: Made a mistake when copying address of IP-device, it is 169.254.241.10

Can you explain the thinking behind this configuration? 1) are you sure you need VLAN tagging? i.e. do you need VLANs specifically, or are you only looking for any kind of virtual interface? if it's the latter – why do you think you need a virtual interface in the first place? 2) if you're trying to communicate with a device addressed .241.1, why are you configuring .241.1 as your own address, and where do the .10 and .100 addresses come from?

@grawity_u1686 the idea is that we can have several optional physical interfaces, and i want a single virtual one, where all of the incoming broadcasts can be sniffed. The device's IP is .241.11 not 241.1, i made a mistake when writing a question

So the Linux system is .10 and the device is .11? Can you clarify whether you're trying to only receive broadcasts, or whether you're trying to send commands to the .11 device, or both?

@grawity_u1686 Sorry, I totally confused you, device's IP is .241.10., .241.11 can be another connected IP-device on a different interface. Linux System's is (as far as I understood netplan's documentation) set to .241.1

Right, okay, but is the communication bidirectional or only in a single direction? (Is it done using regular UDP sockets or using raw sockets or using libpcap?) It sounds like there can be multiple devices connected to eth0, eth1, etc. and you want to receive from all of them?

@grawity_u1686 It's bidirectional udp communication, as of now, i am just trying with regular UDP sockets, but later i will need to write a program that might use raw sockets. But in the end does it matter what type of UDP connection i will use? I thought that currently, i need to figure out IP layer of communication

It might matter for the "all interfaces" part, as in general I don't see any good way of achieving that (except in the case of libpcap). Are the devices guaranteed to have unique IP addresses, at least?
